# An exception in Tomcat 9.0.31 if is SSL-enabled (happens only via VPN with reduced MTU)

Tags: ssl, tomcat, vpn, mtu

I've experienced a strangest issue with an ugly tomcat 9.0.31 app written by 3rd-party. It works with no issues from office, but always throws exceptions at random operations while we work with it via VPN (where MTU is 1400). If we turn off SSL, it starts working with no issues via VPN as well as from the office.

This is the actual errormessage (it cannot be, leider, copypasted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwPZ6.jpg)

This is the relevant part of server.xml config:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxPostSize="-1"
           packetSize="1360"
           redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxThreads="200"
           maxPostSize="-1"
           packetSize="1360"
           scheme="https"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/cert/******.pfx"
           keystorePass="**********"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreType="PKCS12" />

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
```

Please, share any hints, ideas where to start to find a resolution? What to check? The developer (the 3rd-party) sagt nur: "Netzwerk, Netzwerk!", so no real help from them at all. Many many thanks in advance!

Ulrich

Comment: Unfortunately the [library they are using](http://captaincasa.org/licensing) is _free_ as in free beer: _no cost, no source code_.